# Time Log/User Login Tracking Software

Tags: windows, time-management

I'm looking for some software that will act as a time clock. The only thing I'm interested in tracking is when users log on or log off their PCs. I need to be able to generate a report, having it done automatically would be a bonus. I don't want the users to have to do anything though. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Windows or Linux? Please specify

Comment: Sorry - Windows systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two apps that can exactly help you with that. The first one is the [DeskTime](https://desktime.com/) Its has all the requirements you mentioned above. The automatic time tracking,Auto generating reports things like that. You can even analyse things on graphs on this thing. And the second app i would recommend is [Chrometa](http://www.chrometa.com/).This app is great too you can even track time on smartphone with this app and generate a time sheet of everything.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend you [Staff Timer App](https://stafftimerapp.com)

Staff Timer App is a web-based application which provides real-time monitoring, task tracking, and project management solutions to customers globally, working with remote or in-house teams.

Comment: Welcome Candice!  Do you have any affiliation with this product?  If so, please indicate in your answer.  Either way, thank you for your contribution!